# Regex match without consuming

Tags: regex, go

Given the following string two matches should be returned:

```
wednesdayes
```

Both `wednesday` and `yes` should be captured. Doing this is possible in a language that supports lookaheads (which the Go stdlib does not) using the following:

```
(?=(wednesday))|(?=(yes))
```

Is there an alternative to lookahead in the Go stdlib, or is there a way to perform this match without using a lookahead?

Comment: would it happen to have anything to do with today's advent of code's problem? :)

Comment: It would! It's rather frustrating not having access to lookahead, so I am wondering if I am missing another solution

Comment: successive finds with start index, I'd say. But as a single regex, I don't think so.

Comment: For your current sample you could use three capture groups [`(wednesda(y))(es)`](https://regex101.com/r/6by1Tt/1). Have a look at [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/6by1Tt/1), though this won't work with alternation for matching any of the options alone. :p

Answer (score -2):

Use this regex instead:

```
(?:wednesday|yes)
```

Comment: This will match `"wednesday"`, after which the regex engine's string pointer will immediately precede the final `"e"`, so there be no further matches.